# PHPUnit web test error while sending headers in the test

Tags: php, rest, symfony, phpunit

I have written a REST API in symfony. It accepts a Json request and generates a formatted pdf with [FPDF library](https://github.com/Setasign/FPDF) as response.

I want  to write a phpunit web test which will check response status and header data.

```
public function test_getCertificate()
{
    $client = $this->getClient(['username'=>'user','password'=>'xxxxxx']);

    $client->request(
        'GET',
        '/api/v1/certificate',
        array(),
        array(),
        array('CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'),
        null
    );

    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());

    $this->assertTrue(
        $client->getResponse()->headers->contains(
            'Content-Type',
            'application/x-download'
        )
    );

    $this->assertTrue(
        $client->getResponse()->headers->contains(
            'Content-Disposition',
            'attachment; filename="el_certificate.pdf"'
        )
    );
}
```

The problem is that when run test, PHPUnit already start output header and then my controller has problem to generate PDF:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Exception: "FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file"
```

header() is called by the library code which I cannot modify. When I try to clean the output buffer in my Test script with ob_end_clean() or start new buffer with ob_start() then getting exception:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning: "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Printer.php:134)"
```

Versions `PHP 7.2.2-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1`, `PHPUnit 5.1.3`

Any advice how to handle situation like this?

**EDIT:**
I tried to run this test in a separate process:

```
/**
 * @runInSeparateProcess
 * @preserveGlobalState disabled
 */
public function test_getCertificate()
{
    //...
}
```

Then, I got error:

```
PHP Warning:  Uncaught require_once(/var/cache/test/jms_diextra/doctrine/EntityManager_5a9419b75e6b1.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

/vendor/symfony/phpunit-bridge/DeprecationErrorHandler.php:108
/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:2456
/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:2456
/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:329
/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:8179
/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:329
/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:7994
/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:329
/var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:7954
/var/www/html/elearning-ap in /var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php on line 2456
PHP Fatal error:  appTestDebugProjectContainer::getDoctrine_Orm_DefaultEntityManagerService(): Failed opening required '/var/cache/test/jms_diextra/doctrine/EntityManager_5a9419b75e6b1.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php on line 2456
test_getPhases
{"error":{"code":500,"message":"Internal Server Error","exception":[{"message":"Compile Error: appTestDebugProjectContainer::getDoctrine_Orm_DefaultEntityManagerService(): Failed opening required '\/var\/cache\/test\/jms_diextra\/doctrine\/EntityManager_5a9419b75e6b1.php' (include_path='.:\/usr\/share\/php')","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","trace":[{"namespace":"","short_class":"","class":"","type":"","function":"","file":"\/var\/cache\/test\/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php","line":2456,"args":[]}]}]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally figured out what happening.

If PHPUnit should test some code that emits headers (e.g. generate file) the test should  ran in a separated process. That could be achieved [using annotation](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.runInSeparateProcess) :

```
/**
 * @runInSeparateProcess
 * @preserveGlobalState disabled
 */
public function test_getCertificate()
{
    //...
}
```

In my case, JMSDiExtraBundle produced errors because is wrapping it in its own proxy object. If don't want JMSDiExtra generate proxy classes to doctrine then can be added the following configuration:

```
jms_di_extra:
    doctrine_integration: false
```

After that, test can run properly in separate process without problems with header output.